# To get text from textfield

Tags: actionscript-3

I am adding a `textfield` in a movieclip and adding that to a backround bg.Here is the code for that::

```
                        box = new boxMc();
                        bg.addChild(box);
                        box.x=boxX;
                        box.y=boxY;

                        exampleText="<p class='sarath'>"+k+"</p>";
                        boxVal = new TextField()
                        box.addChild(boxVal);
                        boxVal.styleSheet=sheet;
                        boxVal.htmlText=exampleText;
                        boxX=boxX+28        
                        boxArray.push(box)
```

Now i want to retrive the text from the textbox `boxVal`..and I tried as follow::

```
for(var j:Number =0;j<boxArray.length;j++)
                {
                    var mc:MovieClip = boxArray[j] as MovieClip;
                    trace(mc.getChildAt(1).text)
}
```

when am tracing `mc.getChild(1)`,it is displaying as `TEXTFIELD`,but `trace(mc.getChildAt(1).text)`
gives me the following error

```
1119: Access of possibly undefined property text through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

Comment: Try `TextField(mc.getChildAt(1)).text`

Answer (score 1):

putvande is right, but you may want to know why.

getChild returns a DisplayObject and DisplayObjects do not have a text property. You need to 'cast' the returned DisplayObject to one of its subclasses (in this case TextField) which DOES have a text property.

Effectively, TextField(mc.getChildAt(1)) 'converts' the DisplayObject returned by getChildAt() to a TextField. You can then happily access .text and any of the other TextField properties.